# Starting rails server as deamon doesn't trigger worker cluster

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, puma

I want to start the rails server in production mode as a deamon running a worker cluster. When I start my rails program everything works as expected.

```
rails s -e production -b 0.0.0.0
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.0.1 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
[12340] Puma starting in cluster mode...
[12340] * Version 3.4.0 (ruby 2.3.0-p0), codename: Owl Bowl Brawl
[12340] * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
[12340] * Environment: production
[12340] * Process workers: 3
[12340] * Preloading application
[12340] * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
[12340] Use Ctrl-C to stop
[12340] - Worker 0 (pid: 12347) booted, phase: 0
[12340] - Worker 1 (pid: 12349) booted, phase: 0
[12340] - Worker 2 (pid: 12353) booted, phase: 0
```

however when I add the -d rails starts in single mode, confirmed by checking running processes

```
rails s -e production -b 0.0.0.0 -d
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.0.1 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
```

checking running processes confirms only one instance is running, not the clustered mode expected.

So, how do I correctly launch with workers as a deamon process?

Any help is much appreciated.

NOTE: I am also running puma_worker_killer for rolling restarts in case that helps.

rails (5.0.0.1)
puma (3.4.0)
puma_worker_killer (0.1.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Puma docs, it's [recommended](https://github.com/puma/puma#rails) that you start with `bundle exec puma`.

You can then [start a cluster](https://github.com/puma/puma#clustered-mode) like this: `puma -t 8:32 -w 3`. Where `-t` is the min:max number of threads and `-w` is the number of workers.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I will definitely look into this. It doesn't really help me understand though why the rails server boot works one way and not the other though.

Comment: It seems as of rails 5 I should be able to use it directly through rails server command so I am still a bit lost.

Comment: Ok, I have read around the topic some more and I am still a bit fuzzy but things are definitely clearer. I will carry on trying the direct puma boot. @tomdunning Can you tell what if anything I would miss out on if I boot using exec puma rather than rails s?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying, blame new year. You wouldn’t lose anything using puma rather than rails, in production, from what I can see. In dev you could possibly lose the automatic refresh. I haven’t checked. Please can you first try disabling the killer? After that try setting up a puma config file. Let me know how it goes

Comment: No problem, thanks for your help on this. I took out the killer and nothing changed. Using Puma directly as per your recommendation seems to be working fine for me, I haven't hit any errors in production and the process is deamonising just fine. All the initialisers seem to be proc-ing also so I think I am just going to make the switch and move on with life.